# CngProvider.SetProviderProperty in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptoapi, cng

How to set a CNG provider property with .NET?

There is a `CngKey.SetProperty` method, but under the hood it calls `SetKeyProperty`. How to call `SetProviderProperty` instead? CngProvider does not seem to have a `SetProperty` method.